# Cannot reinstall ubuntu after I messed up with my video card or something

Tags: system-installation, dell

After I messed up my video card drive or something, I decided to reinstall ubuntu. I downloaded the usb driver and follow the instructions here (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick). After I hit "Install Ubuntu" but before I can select any language (as indicted by the post), the screen looks like this:

[The error message shown on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzLzE.jpg)

Though clearly my video card is messed up, I can read the following:

> This Dell Recovery Media can be used to restore the original factory software. It is recommended you back up all important data before running this tool. blablabla.

Then the "Back" and "Continue" (This is exactly what I want to click) buttons are disabled. What should I do to continue the installation process?

Comment: Install Win8, erase the disk, install ubuntu again, works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your boot order or use boot options to select your flash drive. It appears that you are booting into the Dell recovery partition (which isn't what you seem to want.